# createArrayOf string in hsqldb.jdbc returns AbstractMethodError

Tags: jdbc, hsqldb, ojdbc

I am writing test cases for my java program that runs with an Oracle database. My code is :

```
st = conn.prepareStatement( MY_QUERY, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            Array array  = conn.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", ids);
            st.setArray(1, array);
            rs = st.executeQuery();
```

where the query is

```
QUERY = "SELECT * from TABLE where id in ?"
```

We are using the hsqldb database for our testing. However, running the above code in tests gives

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.createArrayOf(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Array;
```

on the `createArrayOf` line.

I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem. Would appreciate any help given. Thanks

Comment: What version of HSQLDB are you using? The method [`createArrayOf(String typeName, Object[] elements)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-) was added in Java 1.6 (or JDBC 4), so it looks like your version of HSQLDB doesn't implement JDBC 4.

Comment: My version is `1.8.0.9` . I am using this since our Spring version is `3.1.1` and that was the HSQLDB version used then. Should I upgrade and see?

Comment: As far as I know, HSQLDB 1.8.x only supports (parts of) JDBC 3. The latest is 2.3.3, but I don't know the level of JDBC 4 support in that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [official HSQLDB JavaDoc](http://hsqldb.org/doc/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCConnection.html#createArrayOf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[])) (Version 2.x) of the class `JDBCConnection` (which implements `java.sql.Connection`) the `createArrayOf` method is availble and documented:

> createArrayOf
>
> public Array createArrayOf(String typeName,
>                              Object[] elements)
>                       throws SQLException

This method is supported since HSQLDB version 2.x. Therefore, you should **update** your application to use the **latest HSQLDB driver** which can be [downloaded here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/files/hsqldb/hsqldb_2_3/).

According to the [changelist](http://hsqldb.org/doc/changelist_2_0.txt), you should use at least version 2.2.1 of HSQLDB driver as the dev team "*fixed type limitations of Connection#createArrayOf*" method with this release.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query syntax is different in HSQLDB:

```
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE id IN(UNNEST(?))
```